# Why isn't the value for a new Boolean field rendered?

Tags: nodes

I added a new Boolean field to a content type. For some nodes, I did set this field.

> [image: node edit form]

Still, the field value is not shown on the node page.

> [image: node view]

Why?

I realize that, as long no value is set for the new field, it isn't present in the database, but (as seen in the screenshots) on that node, the field is set to *true* and it should be shown on the node page, shouldn't it?

Comment: Did check the display mode of your node, the field it may be hidden ?

Comment: How it's rendered depends from the display formatter. For example, a display formatter could render it _yes_ when the field checkbox is selected.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, the D7 formatter only has default or KEY, the formatter you mention is available only in D8 or for D7 through a separate module https://www.drupal.org/project/boolean_formatter

Comment: @berramou no, the field is not hidden, as you can see the label being rendered in the screenshot.
Anyways, thanks both! It still helped my own thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Durpal 7 Problem.
It lies about that it will fall back to 0/1 if you don't provide your custom true/false values, when it actually does not fall back.
See
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1750950

In short, in the field-settings, you have to set on-/off- values.
If you don't the default renderer will output an empty string and in the edit forms the field's checkbox or radio-buttons will have no label.